# Can't unsubscribe from The Overflow

Tags: support, the-overflow

I've set The Overflow to Off in my settings yet I am still getting them sent to me. Here is a brief account of the attempts to stop it so far:

1. I received the first one, went to settings and turned it off.
2. I still received the second one so again went to settings to make sure
   I'd turned it off, I had but I repeated the processes in case there
   was some sort of sync issue.
3. I just received the third one. I checked again and the setting is still set to Off.

The only other reason I can think this might happen is if I had multiple accounts with the same email address which I don't believe to be the case.

Can someone investigate what the issue is and advise how I turn this off?

Comment: I didn't know there was a setting in user profiles, I simply unsubscribed via the unsub link in the email footer. Funnily enough, that didn't toggle the option in settings and it still appears to be "on".

Comment: Thanks @SamuelLiew, I'd prefer to use the actual UI to do it but I'll keep that method in mind should it be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I did have a second account I wasn't aware of!

[image]

I got suspicious after logging into an email account I hardly use and noticing it only had 1 copy of The Overflow in it. Sure enough, my Stack Overflow account is linked to *that* e-mail address (which indicates that the subscription setting in the profile is working as expected).

After performing a password reset on the email address that was receiving The Overflow erroneously I found it was linked to its own SO account which did not have the subscription setting set to Off.

To resolve the issue completely I deleted the feral account from within the profile.

Comment: Sorry for all the emails. Glad you found a solution to the problem.

Comment: Nothing to apologise for Ben, user error at the end of the day, and a trivial matter in the grand scheme of things even if there was. Still, appreciated none the less.